# SVG element width not scaling with respect to aspect ratio in IE

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm trying to set the height of an SVG element to 30% but for some reason the total width of the element appears to be 100% in IE. The SVG is viewing properly but the `cursor:pointer` property appears throughout the white space. I want the element width to be with respect to aspect ratio.

This is my page http://jsbin.com/zojiti

For some reason if I use `<img src="speaker.svg"/>` it works completely fine on IE.

Edit: I am using IE 11, chrome and firefox for testing. Everything is working as expected in chrome and firefox.

Tried it with svg under svg
[image]
[image]

Comment: Try to surrend the svg <div style="height:30%"> and change svg height to 100% and see, let me know

Comment: I just tried it and it didn't work

Comment: which version of IE, it works for me

Comment: IE 11. Post the code on jsbin or jsfiddle

Comment: Give me some time I will double check I have test it on jsbin, but now i am going on my jsfiddle to find out.

Comment: OK, it works for me the height on explorer, but for some reason when i have the code on fiddler it does not work correctly. here is what i did 

1. change the svg class height to 100%
2. <div style="height:30%"><svg.....>.....</svg></div>
3. I test it as html file in my local env. with explorer and it works, let me know thx

Comment: Can you post the link to jsfiddle and jsbin?

Comment: sure i will do it shortly

Comment: Here is fiddler it works on all firefox, chrome and IE tested, if this works for you too. I will make it as offical answer  [Fiddler link](http://jsfiddle.net/maythamfahmi/bajkbbq5/11/)

Comment: I did a little mistake before therefore it did not worked on fiddler. regarding jsbin i have no account but i just test it with your code on jsbin

Comment: Go a head it is the correct one

Comment: I tried it on with IE and it's still not working here. I have no idea why.

Comment: how to you run the file from web server OR just start it as file from windows?

Comment: here is my [test](https://photos-3.dropbox.com/t/2/AAD3e7qX8pg6zak_4UyNzxVOA-qSs6ooKiAV5Tv73kZq8w/12/107220852/jpeg/32x32/3/_/1/2/svg-test.jpg/CPSekDMgAyACIAEoAygCKAE/FpdXd_fxqHieE8npm4_5n3mnEGPpYeMQK0_F7Ob36kU?size=1024x768) results.

Comment: and it works only from webserver local or global, does not work correctly if you just start the file from windows

Comment: I checked the jsfiddle page. check the edit i posted a screenshot. and your dropbox link isnt working

Comment: In my scope i do not have more to be think of, continue asking and see if others have some thing to add that i missed.

Comment: shortly i will send you the file that i ran on my local apache server which work, and try the file from your web server, let us not trust any thrid part for moment. here is the file https://www.dropbox.com/sh/7g7xtzjtmbum60c/AABKQLzwP6QhvNG1ZRGSiazWa?dl=0 download it and test it. let me know as last chance

Comment: Nope. Check the edit for screenshot.

Comment: I suggest you delete this question and start fresh again with what you achived until now. sorry and good luck dude